# My listview makes all the objects in my layout disappear

Tags: java, android, listview

I have this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#3F51B5"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="171dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="87dp"
        android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></ListView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

when I see the layout on the Design window it's correct, but when I run it on my phone, the relative layout disappear and the listview takes the whole layout.

I just want to split the screen in 2 parts:
a relative layout in the superior part and a listview under this layout. What I get is only the listview in full screen mode.
As i told you before, when I watch the layout in the design window, it's how I desire.

[Picture of design View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65WkB.jpg)

Comment: do you need to use <RelativeLayout> everywhere? If you just have two elements for now, have you tried replacing <RelativeLayout> with <LinearLayout>?

Answer (score 0):

I've no way to test it, but the idea is to add `android:layout_below="@+id/textView3` in `ListView`.
Try below code and let me know;

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#3F51B5"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="171dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="87dp"
        android:text="TextView" />


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <ListView
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I still get the same issue. I can not even see the textView or the blue colour

Comment: Don't worry, I'll come with tested solution for you as soon as I get home, Hope someone else helps you in meanwhile.

Comment: Try working around with `android:layout_below="@+id/your_id` property, I'm sure It'll work

Comment: ugh it does not work with this command. maybe it could be something in the code (layout inflater). May it be?

Comment: I don't think so, But don't worry, Try working on rest of your app, I'll get you the solution soon